# Amended value of input not retrieved by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I've encounter a very strange situation. In my troubleshooting, I have added `value="test"` in the text field and added `console.log($('input[name*="name"]').val());` so the whole code looks like this:

```js
$('body').on('click', 'input[type="button"][name*="review"]', function() {
    console.log($('input[name*="name"]').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="textfield-name" placeholder="Required" value="test" >
<input type="button" name="review" value="Review" />
```

In the console, it will now say "test" as expected. But if I remove "test" from the text field's value and type in something random like "dsa", it will say... nothing at all! Just a blank row in the console! If I add text after `test` it will only show "test" and not the text I've typed in.

The code I use, is **exactly** the same as the code above and it worked perfectly the day before yesterday. I have not edited or added anything else during the time between 2 days ago till now, since I was on a one day long trip yesterday.

If I run the code in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jx0o31f9/), it will execute everything as normal.

I also have tested to remove everything in my JavaScript file and only leaved the code above within `$(document).ready(function() { ... }`. The result is the same as mentioned. This applies also when I tested to remove everything in the HTML file and only kept the input.

I have also tested to replace `.val()` with `.prop('value')` but the result is the same.

In short, all text that I type in to the text field, are completely ignored by the website!

Excuse my language, but what the h*** is going one here?! Is this some sort of bug or what?

Comment: link to website ?

Comment: I placed your code in the question in a runnable snippet. You can see that it now works fine. The only way I can see the behaviour you describe happening is if the `input[name*="name"]` selector matches multiple elements, and the one you've changed was not the first in the DOM: https://jsfiddle.net/jx0o31f9/1/

Comment: $('input[name*="name"]') .val() this code return the first catched element's value.   you may miss this

Comment: Yea there must be multiple element with same selector in the page. Just check by inspecting

Comment: Rory: It works fine in the jsFiddle too. But if you click on the link I've added in my first comment above, it will return empty. Like I said in my question (I thought you read everything I wrote?), I tested to remove everything in both the HTML file and in the JavaScript file - the problem is still there!

Comment: yogen: I have already done that (please read my whole question!). If nothing else was in the HTML file and the JavaScript file, how could this problem still exists?

Comment: If you check the HTML in the inspector you will see that the issue is as I described, you have several repeated elements all with `name="textfield-name"`. That's the problem. Check out your hidden `#comment` div for the first one. The one you're actually trying to target is in the `#review` div.

Comment: `(I thought you read everything I wrote?)` I did, but after a while being on this site you trust the outcome more than what people say ;)

Comment: Rory: Thank you! I have completely missed that! But I think it's still strange that the problem existed even in my troubleshooting! But to add the post's ID in the input's, this problem was after that gone!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is now solved, thanks to Rory McCrossan!

The problem was that multiple text fields with the same name, existed on the same page. I added the post ID into a `data` properties (`data="1"`) and the problem was after that gone.

Many thanks for opening my eyes, Rory!